# Get json string elements

Tags: php, json

I am using a astrology API which sends an json string as response to the query. But i have been trying for long to convert it into json and retrieve different items from the response string. Here is the example of the response:

```
{"ashtakoota":{"status":true,"received_points":26},"manglik":{"status":true,"male_percentage":13.25,"female_percentage":13.75},"rajju_dosha":{"status":false},"vedha_dosha":{"status":false},"conclusion":{"match_report":"Marriage between the prospective bride and groom is highly recommended. The couple would have a long-lasting relationship, which would be filled with happiness and affluence."}}
```

I am using php script so i tried the following code :

`$json = json_decode($res1, true);
 TRY 1 --> echo array_values($json[1]);
 TRY 2 --> echo $json.ashtakoota.status;
 TRY 3 --> echo $res1.ashtakoota.status;`

But the output is always blank. I doubt that $json is empty or the json response is not perfectly json.

Comment: try 4 : $json['ashtakoota']['status']

Comment: Thanks alot friend. it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP uses string keys for its arrays, which is what `json_decode(...)` returns. As such, you need to access them as:

```
echo $json['ashtakoota']['status'];
```

Which should then output `true` for your example JSON input.

Comment: it worked bro. Thanks a lot. It actually returned 1 instead of true. :p

Answer (score 1):

The true parameter on json_decode will cause it to return an array, not an object. Your syntax for objects is also incorrect, it's not a dot, but rather `->` that you need.

```
$json = json_decode($res1);

echo $json->ashtakoota->status;
```

Comment: it didn't worked man. But spenderD answer worked. Again thanks for trying friend